# How to get internal link from latest revision of a wikipedia page?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to extract internal links from wikipedia pages. This is the query I'm using

```
/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&format=xml&plnamespace=0&pllimit=max&titles=pageTitle
```

However, the result does not reflect what's on the wiki page. Take for example a random article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution). There are only a dozen of links on this page. However, when I make the query,

```
/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&format=xml&plnamespace=0&pllimit=max&titles=Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution
```

I got back 187 links. I guess the API might has a database of all the links that have ever added to the page including all the revisions. Is that the case? How can I get the links from only the last revision?

Comment: Could it be that you forgot about the links in the navigation box? From what I can see all links from the API reply are in the page. Can you give an example of a link that shouldn't be there?

Comment: +1. You are right, leo. Unfortunately, the API does not allow me to specify which section of the page to extract links from :(

Answer (score 5):

The database has the correct list of the links in the current version of the articles. All the links you get from the API are in fact in the article. However, most of them are hidden in the (twice collapsed) navigation box at the bottom (scroll to the bottom, click "show" on the blue bar, then click "show" on the additional blue bars you now see).

Note that these links are on the page, but not defined in the wikitext - they come from the {{ProbDistributions}} navigation template (and the template that template in turn includes).

Sadly, there is no good way to list only the links that are directly/explicitly defined on a page, since template substitution happens before the actual parsing of the wiki syntax.

Comment: +1. I see. It makes thing more complicated than I expected. In this case, I guess the best way is to parse the wikitext. but do you know any available parser that is good for this job? Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, the MediaWiki syntax is very convoluted, and calling the thing that turns it into HTML a "parser" is using the term very losely. That makes it very hard to re-implement the exact behavior of the "canonical" parser. The closes we have got is Parsoid, but there is a bunch of "decent" parsers that should be good enough to get you the links. Have a look here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: If all you want is extract the links, you can probably use code from the PyWikipedia framework or a simmilar library. Soo also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968132/how-to-parse-extract-data-from-a-mediawiki-marked-up-article-via-python